# limit vector.size() in a for loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do this in a vector composed of Vec3f:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < (mPoints.size() - 10) ; i++) {
    glVertex3f(mPoints[i]);
}
```

But I always get a run time error EXC_BAD_ACCESS ... if instead of size() I use an int I get the same error. If instead I simply use size() without the substraction, it works fine...

What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you are possibly running into a problem where the vector has less than 10 elements in it.  So when you subtract 10 from an unsigned value it's possible for the implementation to wrap around and give you a very large number (basically max - 10).  Hence you try and iterate past the bounds of the vector.

Try the following instead

```
for (size_t i = 0; i + 10 < vector.size(); i++) {
  glVertex3f(mPoints[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! But what puzzles me is that the vector has hundreds of elements...

Comment: @Pier are you sure that was the case in every instance? I can't see how the original code would be a problem when the vectory had more than 10 elements.

Comment: Hmmmm... I see the problem now. The draw function was called before the function that creates the points. So the first time there were no points in the vector.